# File contents created when opened

Tags: linux, files

What I want is this:

Having a file called `file` somewhere in the filesystem with a content something like:

```
#!/bin/whatever-interpreter-you-want
echo 'line1'
echo 'line2'
```

When ANY (almost any since must exist a way to edit the script itself) program opens  `file` to read it gets:

```
line1
line2
```

As its contents instead of:

```
#!/bin/whatever-interpreter-you-want
echo 'line1'
echo 'line2'
```

Something like file contents being executed on the fly by the filesystem or the kernel itself (please, no cron, no inotify, no duct tape).

Comment: Can you please explain what you need this for? There might be a simpler way to accomplish it.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible: A file is either executed or read.

Comment: If you are willing to open a different file, then the different file can be a pipe, and the program would have to be modified to write to the pipe, close the pipe, and loop (in case the file was opened for reading again).

Comment: @JosephR. My question is largely hypothetical, but I can think in something like a system with centralized configuration in Sqlite database and `/etc/` full of these scripts querying such database when a daemon (or another program) opens them for reading. I've discarded cron because I want the files contents being generated just before they are opened, and I don't want a daemon regenerating these files from time to time. I don't know if applicable, but I discarded inotify too because I consider it very linux-specific.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273812/have-a-file-generate-its-content-on-demand.

Answer (score 2):

This can certainly be achieved using FUSE.  Without exact details of your goals I've provided some details of FUSE below.

- [Wikipedia: Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)

  > Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE) is an operating system mechanism for
  >   Unix-like computer operating systems that lets non-privileged users
  >   create their own file systems without editing kernel code.
- [Example : Filesystem in Userspace](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)
- Diagram of FUSE

  [image: FUSE example]

Answer (score 1):

You might put your file in some [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) filesystem. You'll then need to write some FUSE server to handle IO to such files. It might take you some significant effort (so I am not sure it is worth the pain)